# How to pass array to funtion to use as range based for loop

Tags: c++, c++14

```
void sortArray(int arr[])
{
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int count0s{0},count1s{0},count2s{0};
     for (int n: arr)
     {

     }

}
int main()
{
    //some code here including creating array arr
        sortArray(arr);
        TestCases--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I want to use range-based for loop in `sortArray` function but I don't know how to pass it.
[image]

Comment: there is no array in your code. Did you erase lines before posting it here?

Comment: You cannot pass an array to a function in C++ (unless you use references and templates). This is a good reason not to use arrays. In C++ it's better to use a vector. All the problems with arrays disappear when you use a vector.

Comment: BTW `sizeof` will not work either. The fundmental problem is that in your code `arr` is not an array, it's a pointer.

Comment: An argument of the form `int arr[]` is passed as a pointer that carries *no information* about the number of elements in the passed array, or how to find the end of the array. A range-based for loop *requires* such information. Also, the `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` trick does not give the number of elements when `arr` is a pointer. If you insist on using a range-based loop, pass something else - such as `std::array<int, num>` (where `num` is the number of elements specified at COMPILE time) or using a `std::vector<int>` (number of contained elements determined at run time).

Answer (score 2):

parameter `int arr[/*N*/]` is in fact a pointer, (you cannot pass C-array by value).

but you can pass it by reference (syntax might surprise):

```
template <std::size_t N>
void sortArray(int (&arr)[N])
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: ok. but I'm confused about where the size of the array which is N is coming from. does it automatically taking the size depending upon the address where the array is stored

Comment: Here, I used template to allow deduction from call site, but if size is known, you might use instead `void sortArray(int (&arr)[42])`. (you sample misses that information).

Comment: @AniketUjgare You would have to pass it in with the same size as it was created in the code above (that you omitted). As you can see people are trying to be helpful and provide all kinds of options. You might want to consider to specify what you really want by showing the declaration of  the array, to spare them some effort.

Comment: This requires the number of elements at the call site to be known at compile time.   Also, a different instantiation of the template is generated for every distinct value of `N`  (e.g. an array with 2 elements is passed to a different instance of the template function than an array with 3 elements).

Answer (score 1):

You can use C++ `std::array`:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void sortArray(std::array<int, 5> &arr)
{

    int count0s{0},count1s{0},count2s{0};
     for (int n: arr)
     {

     }

}
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 5> arr;
    sortArray(arr);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Or C++ `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void sortArray(std::vector<int> &arr)
{

    int count0s{0},count1s{0},count2s{0};
     for (int n: arr)
     {

     }

}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr;
    sortArray(arr);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Use a template to avoid a fixed size and type in the function:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void sortArray(T &arr)
{
    int count0s{0},count1s{0},count2s{0};
    for (int n: arr)
    {
    }
}
int main()
{
    // it works with C arrays
    int arr[5];
    sortArray(arr);
    std::array<int, 5> arr2;
    sortArray(arr2);
    std::array<double, 5> arr3;
    sortArray(arr3);
    std::vector<double> arr4;
    sortArray(arr4);

    return 0;
}
```

With C++20 you can

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void sortArray(auto &arr)
{
    int count0s{0},count1s{0},count2s{0};
    for (int n: arr)
    {
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    sortArray(arr);
    std::array<int, 5> arr2;
    sortArray(arr2);
    std::array<double, 5> arr3;
    sortArray(arr3);
    std::vector<double> arr4;
    sortArray(arr4);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since c++20, you can use `std::span<T>`

```
void func(std::span<int> values) {
    for(auto& i : values) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    int* arr = new int[5]{0,1,2,3,4};
    func({arr,5});
}
```